# Pressist CFUUIDRef After App Deleted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

Recently apple has reject apps that uses the unique device identifier (`UDID`), in my app i am creating once a`CFUUIDRef` for each device on the first time, which works great. 
in my app i am giving to a new user 10 clicks on a button (some service), when i am creating a device id for the first time it sends to the server and this id is now have credit of 10 clicks.
the problem is when the user delete my app it generate a new identifier.
how can i write some file to the iphone withe an identifier lets say for example "MyCustomDeviceID"
and when a user download the app i am checkin if this file is existing, if it does i am getting the saved parameter and if it doesn't i am creating the identifier and then creating the document.
i got to have some way to leave a mark on the iphone.

ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you can convert a `CFUUIDRef` into an `NSString`, you can store it in the keychain. Items stored in the keychain persist across app deletes. Check out [PDKeychainBindingsController](https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS you have no "shared space" where save data and maintain it after the application deletion. You have to do it in other ways:

- you can enable iCloud for your app and save your id using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.
- You can save your identifier in NSUserDefaults, so if the app is deleted and then reinstalled it will be available in the backup. (obviously the user have to restore from backup)
- Or you can associate the identifier to a nominal account. (you have to create a system where the user can do a registration and login with this nominal account)

Comment: lets say i am uploading string object with the key "str".
every device that will call this "str" will get the object or only the device who upload it?

Comment: If you are talking about the iCloud solution, yes. NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is meant to "syncronize" preferences through different devices. If you need to differentiate the devices, you have to add more controls. For example, you can query [[UIDevice currentDevice] name] and change the iCloud key using something like @"str_deviceName" :-)